# Slither command not found in my MAC

Tags: slither

I installed Slither in my directory[image: Slither Installed]

However, when I enter slither . or slither hello.sol Doesn't work.

I checked to see if it was the $PATH for python in my Mac and I think that is the issue. I don't know which $PATH I should set so that Slither runs.

Here's some info that could be useful and specific for this:

[image: pwd]

My PATH:

[image]

Comment: From the error message it appears to be installed in `/Users/david/Library/Python/3.8/`. I'd check for the slither command in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, to solve it ran the following installation command inside the vscode terminal instead of running it in the normal mac terminal:

> pip3 install slither-analyzer

I followed this guide: https://coinsbench.com/simplest-way-to-run-slither-for-your-smart-contract-project-4bdb367c06e2